# Making on onClick to change text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a format like the following:

Phrase
[Button]

When the button is clicked, the 'phrase' changes and the button remains. I am able to make it so text appears, however I can not make it so the button stays. Does anyone have an idea of how this may be done?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events).

Comment: Thank you, I knew I saw how to do it somewhere and it was in my first javascript tutorial!

Answer (score 7):

**Final script**

Javascript (replacement)

```
function displayPhrase()
{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'New Phrase';
}
```

HTML (Old phrase)

```
<span id="demo">Old Phrase</span>
```

HTML (The button)

```
<button type="button" onclick="displayPhrase()"></button>
```

**Credit to above answers ^_^**

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to make it so text appears, however I can not make it so the button stays.

My guess is you are updating the element that also contained the `button` element, and this update is clearing the `button`.

#### HTML

```
<span id="phrase"></span>
<button id="change-phrase" type="button">Change Phrase</button>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var button = document.getElementById('change-phrase'),
    content = document.getElementById('phrase');

button.onclick = function() {
    content.innerHTML = 'Your new phrase';
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ewQEw/).

Answer (score 1):

### Use this code:

**HTML:**

```
<h1> Welcome to the </h2><span id="future-clicked"></span>

<button onclick="clicked_on()">Click for future</button>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    function clicked_on(){
        document.getElementById('future-clicked').innerHTML = 'Future World';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: An explanation to your code would improve the quality of your answer.